# Show that $q\geq p$, $L^q(\Omega) \subset L^p(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis

(*) Theorem. $\lVert f \rVert _{L^p(\Omega)}\leq |\Omega|^{\frac{q-p}{q}} \lVert f \rVert _{L^q(\Omega;\mathbb R^N)}$ when $\Omega$ is bounded.

Proof.
$$ \int_\Omega |f(x)|^p dx \leq \left(\int_\Omega (1)^{\frac{q}{q-p}}\right)^{\frac{q-p}{q}}
\left( (|f(x)|^p)^{\frac qp} dx\right)^{\frac pq} $$
Raising both sides to $\frac 1p$ gives

$$ \lVert f \rVert _{L^p(\Omega)}\leq |\Omega|^{\frac{q-p}{q}} \lVert f \rVert _{L^q(\Omega;\mathbb R^N)} $$

---

I understand how to prove ( * ). But I don't know why ( * ) implies  $q\geq p$, $L^q(\Omega) \subset L^p(\Omega)$. Why is this not $L^p(\Omega) \subset L^q(\Omega)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you show, if $q\geq p$
$$\|f\|_{L^p}\leq C \|f\|_{L^q}$$

and thus, if $f\in L^q$, you have that $\|f\|_{L^q}<\infty $ and thus $\|f\|_{L^p}\leq C\|f\|_{L^q}<\infty $. Therefore $\|f\|_{L^p}<\infty $ and thus $f\in L^p$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was stuck with this.